# ASP.NET - Persisting viewstate to file causes problems with ASP Update panel controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, viewstate

I'm having a problem with drop down list controls in my ASP.NET project which is driving me mad! any and all help appreciated...

I've two DropDownLists on an update panel on my page, DropDownList1 is used as a filter for DropDownList2 which in turn populates a list box. The problem is when the Page viewstate persistence methods below are overridden the following behavior occurs:

1) Select a value in DropDownList1 and DropDownList2 populates accordingly.
2) Select a value in DropDownList2 and the listboxes dont load anything and DropDownList2 loses it's selected value.

The logic in the codebehind for these events dont seem to be the problem as when I remove the Updatepanel from the page it works fine! Silimarly, it works a treat when the updatepanel is present but the viewstate isn't overridden!

I've done some tracing in Visual Studio and it seems as though the event for DropDownList1 is being called for the second postback even though only the event for DropDownList2 should be called, so I'm wondering if there's some kind of "event stack" being held by ASP that is calling the first event even though it's already been called and should be cleared. It works fine for pages without UpdatePanels present.

I've overridden the

```
Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium
```

and

```
Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium
```

to save/load from a text file as per this example:

http://aspalliance.com/911

The following properties have been set on each control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upMain" UpdateMode="Conditional" >

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxFull" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ondatabound="DropDownList1_DataBound">

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxFull" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" ondatabound="DropDownList2_DataBound">
```

Any help appreciated, this has been driving me mad all day.

Thanks.

Comment: really nobody solved this? im going mad also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt figure this one out in the end, so I re-wrote the entire thing inheriting from the PageStatePersister class and it works fine. Sometimes its just better to start from scratch.